# Port mirroring on HP 1820-8G (J9979A)

Tags: switch

I have a HP 1820-8G switch [[German website]](http://www8.hp.com/de/de/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=6627772) with the latest [J9979A firmware [HP]](https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/Downloads/ProductsList.aspx?lang=en&cc=de&prodSeriesId=7687976) at the day of writing. I'm trying to set up port mirroring via the web admin UI.

Whenever I add a source and press the Apply button, the switch hangs, i.e. the web UI does not respond and the switch cannot be pinged any more. The switch itself works, i.e. my PC can still connect to websites.

Is there a fix or workaround possible except pressing the hardware reset button?

Update due to @acejavelin's answer:

I have considered:

- the mirroring port. As per the manual, I'm not trying to connect through the mirroring port. The mirroring port is just used for capturing packets with Wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HP Procurve 18xx series switches do not have a command line interface, either serial or telnet, so assuming connecting to another port on the switch does not work, the only recourse is to reset the switch or possibly power cycle it (if the changes had not been commited due to an error). Are you on the monitor port, because if you are normal traffic and administration cannot occur on that port once it becomes a monitor port, you must switch to a different port to manage switch and disable the monitor.